# how to display a paragraph based on the icon clicked

Tags: javascript

I have 4 paragraph and 4 icons , the paragraph are hidden by default and I want to make them visible with respect to which  icon is clicked . 
 [paragraph are visible here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHldF.png)

```
    <div class="challenge">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-1x" onclick=toggleIcon(this)>
            <i class="fas fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        </span>
        <div class="challenges-heading"><h3>Hand us your toughest challenges</h3></div> 
        <p class="challenges-text">Looking for a custom software or mobile solution? With over a decade of software development experience, we will work with you to create solutions that can help you achieve your goals.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="challenge">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-1x onclick=toggleIcon(this)">
            <i class="fas fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        </span>
        <div class="challenges-heading"> <h3>Get solutions that let your scale</h3></div>
        <p>Quo cu accumsan oporteat neglegentur, reque aeterno consetetur his an. An sanctus sententiae interesset mel, at vis affert iracundia eloquentiam. Dico molestie lucilius at vel. Duo ut quas liber insolens.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="challenge">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-1x" onclick=toggleIcon(this)>
            <i class="fas fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        </span>
        <div class="challenges-heading"> <h3>A seamless</h3></div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, convenire conclusionemque eu vim, mea simul ullamcorper id. Ipsum tamquam te vix. Et unum quidam duo. Democritum dissentiet ne qui, elitr dignissim percipitur quo te.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="challenge">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-1x" onclick=toggleIcon(this)>
            <i class="fas fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        </span>
        <div class="challenges-heading"> <h3>Flexibility to Innovate</h3></div>
        <p class="challenges-text">Melius dissentiet nam ne, vel ei graeco elaboraret, has ei suas oblique pertinacia. Nam cu legendos petentium instructior, voluptua indoctum cum at, dicam tractatos sea te. Eum ne iusto dolores dissentiunt.</p>
    </div>
```

I tried using a JS but it toggles all paragraphs

```
function toggleIcon() {
    $(".challenge .fa-inverse").toggleClass("fa-plus fa-minus")
    $(".challenge p").toggle();
}
```

Comment: What are you doing to make the paragraphs hidden?

Comment: The code is simple enough to add a code snippet to showf what you have tried. Adding a snippet will make it easier for others  to help you.

Comment: display : none ;

Comment: Try This [Jquery Accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: doesnt help ...

Comment: use `this` keyword to toggle particular paragraph ..

Comment: I've used this on function call , can u check ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```js
$(".tooglebtn").on("click",function(){
       $(this).closest('div').find('p').toggleClass("open");
        
    });
```

```css
   .challenge p{
        display:none;
    }
    .challenge p.open{
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="challenge">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-1x tooglebtn" >ICON
                <i class="fas fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i> 
                <i class="fas fa-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>
            <div class="challenges-heading"><h3>Hand us your toughest challenges</h3></div> 
            <p class="challenges-text" >Looking for a custom software or mobile solution? With over a decade of software development experience, we will work with you to create solutions that can help you achieve your goals.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="challenge">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-1x tooglebtn" > ICON
                <i class="fas fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i> 
                <i class="fas fa-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>
            <div class="challenges-heading"> <h3>Get solutions that let your scale</h3></div>
            <p>Quo cu accumsan oporteat neglegentur, reque aeterno consetetur his an. An sanctus sententiae interesset mel, at vis affert iracundia eloquentiam. Dico molestie lucilius at vel. Duo ut quas liber insolens.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="challenge">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-1x tooglebtn">ICON
                <i class="fas fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i> 
                <i class="fas fa-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>
            <div class="challenges-heading"> <h3>A seamless</h3></div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, convenire conclusionemque eu vim, mea simul ullamcorper id. Ipsum tamquam te vix. Et unum quidam duo. Democritum dissentiet ne qui, elitr dignissim percipitur quo te.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="challenge">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-1x tooglebtn">ICON
                <i class="fas fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i> 
                <i class="fas fa-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>
            <div class="challenges-heading"> <h3>Flexibility to Innovate</h3></div>
            <p class="challenges-text">Melius dissentiet nam ne, vel ei graeco elaboraret, has ei suas oblique pertinacia. Nam cu legendos petentium instructior, voluptua indoctum cum at, dicam tractatos sea te. Eum ne iusto dolores dissentiunt.</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: sorry I didn't write the change of icon function. you will write it :)

Comment: icons do not appear because they are not fontawesome. adding "icon" words. clickable is "icon"

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var toggleIcon = function(el) {
  if (!el.parentNode.childNodes[5].style.visibility){
    el.parentNode.childNodes[5].style.visibility = "hidden";    
  } else {
    el.parentNode.childNodes[5].style.visibility = "";  
  }
}
```

This is the `toggleIcon(this)` function definition.

I havent wrote the code for change of icon though.